# nginx configuration. Yii project in separate directory [not in root]

Tags: configuration, yii, nginx, subdirectory

I spent over 6 hours on this trouble.

I have nginx/1.2.7 server, and php-fpm on 127.0.0.1:9000.
I have base nginx config:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;

    index index.php index.html;

    access_log /srv/www/example.org/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/example.org/logs/error.log;

    location /
    {
        root /var/www/html/example.org/public_html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$
        {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

And it works fine! All php files work like they must.

But I have some separate yii-project, which need to execute in other than main root folder.
And I have this configuration added at bottom:

Where ****/srv/www/example.org/yiitest**** — it is a root of yiitest project (with 'protected' folder and other inside it).

```
location /yiitest
    {
        root /srv/www/example.org/yiitest;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$
        {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I've got 'File not found'.
And maximum what I can get, it is: example.org/yiitest/ the main page works fine.
And if I go to example.org/yiitest/site/contact/ I'll get file not found. :(

I can't understand, how to correctly setup yii-project in separate subdirectory of a server.

Comment: I am facing the same kind of issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. create symlink

   ```
   cd /var/www/html/example.org/public_html
   ln -s ../yiitest/public yiitest
   ```
2. configure nginx

   ```
   root /var/www/html/example.org/public_html;

   location / {
       ...
   }

   location /yiitest/ {
       index    index.php;

       # front end
       if (!-e $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /yiitest/index.php last;
           break;
       }
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1: 9000;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
   ```
3. Then configure yii framework. You should set 'basePath' in your config:

   ```
   <?php
   return array(
       'basePath' => 'yiitest',
       ...
   );
   ```